# Storing Sensitive Data with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, security, encryption

I am not incredibly familiar with cryptography, so please bear with me. I am working on an application that needs to store sensitive data in a database. This information; however, needs to be accessible to those with the proper credentials (so hashing is not going to work).

The data is gathered from a PHP form. My idea is to use prepared SQL queries and MySQL's AES_ENCRYPT function to store the keys in the database. Is this secure (if the key is kept safe - the point of my next post) or are there risks associated with this method?

Secondly, how would you recommend generating and storing the key? The problem is that the user who needs to access this sensitive data is not an IT specialist of any form - she simply is not familiar with the tools of the trade. If I only needed to access the data, this would probably not be too difficult, but how would I go about ensuring the security of the key, while allowing the user who is not experienced with databases, easily access it?

Thanks much.

Comment: You need to draw out a diagram of how all this data is moving back and forth. AES is a symmetric key solution. Those keys need to be available to various parties to be useful (encrypt, decrypt). Often called secret keys. I am not so sure how effective it is going to be as a secret key, if it needs to be passed around from server to clients thousands of miles away with dozens of server hops between them and their own storage techniques of them (your users, their storage). Even with a secure channel. PKI solves this. ala the RSA analogy. A public key pair ring. Not issues handed to novices.

Comment: @KellyMarchewa you need to define the level of security, that is who are you protecting against. How will the users access the data, locally or over the Internet? How will they authenticate? How will the server be protected, is the db server connected to the Internet, is two factor authentication to the server used, it there data access throttling, good logging that is reviewed daily, etc.

Comment: I am interested in protection from the 'outside', that is, hackers, rather than anyone internally. Authentication would likely be simply a password. The users would access the data through a database hosted on a remote server provided by a web host (GoDaddy). I am not entirely sure about the security measures in place on the server. I hope this is a bit more to go by. Thanks!

Comment: You need to understand SQL Injection attacks. See [Little Bobby Tables](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png).

Answer (score 0):

If you store the open key, you could also store the plain data, since encrypted data in conjunction with the key actually is plain data. Ok, storing data and keys on separate systems can improve security, but that is not safe yet. Obviously you need to get the secret from the user himself via SSL. This could be a passphrase to unlock a crypto key.

> The problem is that the user who needs to access this sensitive data is not an IT specialist of any form.

This implies that the user will not be comfortable with handling key pairs directly. Thus the alternative with a passphrase should be a reasonable compromise. Nevertheless you should enforce a high quality passphrase to avoid easy bruteforce attacks.

Comment: Actually security is about increasing the work factor to meed the threat. Example: if the need is to defend against the idly curious just encrypting may be sufficient. Protecting against a well funded government is the other extreme.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand SQL Injection attacks. See [Little Bobby Tables](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png).

You need to use two factor authentication for logging into the server.

You need to use HTTPS. You need to store the key above the http directory.

Without a good understanding about the use if encryption it is probably best to use MySQL's AES_ENCRYPT, secure encryption is difficult to get right.

These are minimums that will not protect against a reasonably proficient attacker.